# SDF to URDF converter?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since SDF and URDF are both used in ROS/Gazebo as mentioned in:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/853/should-urdf-in-gazebo-tutorials-be-replaced-with/

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/543/why-does-drcsim-atlas-robot-model-use-urdf/

Is there a way to convert from SDF to URDF? I have a robot in SDF that I want to use with ROS mechanism_controllers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1310/sdf-to-urdf-converter?/) by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sorry, but there currently is no converter from SDF to URDF.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukesh_148](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3726/mukesh_148/) on 2017-08-23**:
hi, sorry for commenting here but I posted my doubt and no one answered.
I have the same problem in using ros. I have SDF file for my model which I got from gazebo and I want to use it in ros rviz. But ros is supporting urdf only.
is it possible to proceed with sdf now ?